# How to debug MSTest while building on Bamboo CI?

Tags: debugging, testing, mstest, bamboo

I like to debug MSTests written in C# when these MSTests run as part of build on Bamboo CI (Continuous Integration) as these tests are running OK on my local machine but fails intermittently on Bamboo Server during build.

Comment: What is the error you are getting when running under CI?  Is it a file not found kind of error (you don't have the correct files copied to the output directory, or what you think it the 'local' directory is not the same on the CI server?

Comment: It's not file not found error. There are in total 15 MSTests, first 5 are not accessing .mdf files and they always pass. But 6th MSTest which uses .mdf files fails intermittently with an application error saying that it can't access a record from mdf file after running a select SQL even though that record is very much exist in mdf. After 1 or 2 failures it will run successfully. These MSTests always pass on my local machine though.

Comment: Is the MDF always accessible from all test servers?  Do some of the tests update the MDF and not restore it to it's prior state.  Tests should not depend on the order they are run (many tests suites automatically randomise test order to highlight this problem), and should be able to be run in parallel.  Perhaps your tests depend on them being run in the same order, which they do locally, but on the server, they don't.

Comment: MDF always accessible from my local machine. All tests use their own MDF so it's not being shared across multiple tests. There is no inter dependency among tests. Initially I suspected that may be server is slow and it takes time to start up MSLocalDB so I am explicitly starting up MSLocalDB during assembly initialization. But that also didn't fix the issue. Is there a way to debug the Test code while it's building on Bamboo CI server?

Comment: Can you write to a log the path/filename of the MDF file when you run it on Bamboo, then you can see where the file it's actually to load is.  it might not be where you expect it to be, or it might be loading the mdf for a different test.